# DOM Elements in Blockly

Tags: javascript, blockly

I am currently learning about blockly, there are already many predefined blocks in blockly. Are there any predefined blocks in blockly for DOM Elements in the toolbox? If there aren't any can anyone just demonstrate how to create a DOM Element like a `body` element so that I can understand the procedure and generating code for the same, I went through the documentation on how to create a custom block, but I am not getting any idea on how to get started for creating these DOM elements.

I will be greatful if anyone can demonstrate on how to create a DOM element using blockly if there aren't any predefined blocks for the same in the toolbox...

Answer (score 1):

The Documentation of blockly gives you an open-source project with different toolbox types you can use.
Doc Link: https://developers.google.com/blockly/guides/get-started/web
Github project: https://github.com/google/blockly.git